# Accessing values from an object in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm aware that properties in objects can be retrieved either .notation or wrapping key as a string expression in a [] suffix. for example

```
var character = {
   "name" : "Gloria",
   "feature" : "Dance"
};

console.log("using .notation: "+character.name);
console.log("using []suffix: "+character["name"]);
```

And it's works pretty well. But, When I do the same by retrieving values from an array of objects, **.Notation** is simply not working. The codes shows below.

```
var info = {
"full_name" : "Some Name",
"title" : "Some title",
"links" : [
        { "blog"     : "http://iviewsource.com" },
        { "facebook" : "http://facebook.com/iviewsource" },
        { "youtube"  : "http://www.youtube.com/planetoftheweb" },
        { "podcast"  : "http://feeds.feedburner.com/authoredcontent" },
        { "twitter"  : "http://twitter.com/planetoftheweb" }
    ]
};
```

then, when I try to retrieve values from each object in an array with the following snippet

```
for(var i = 0; i < info.links.length; i++) {
    for(var key in info.links[i]) {
        console.log("key is: "+key+" and it's value: "+info.links[i][key]);         
    }
}
```

In the above code, to retrieve the values I'm using **info.links[i][key]** and it's works as expected but if I use **info.links[i].key**, it just gives undefined which I'm not expected.
I wonder why? It confuses me a lot.

Comment: That's because `key` is the key it iterates with through the object, not the property

Comment: @Rayon now it's my specific problem. The link you've provided didn't solve my problem. So could you remove duplicate tag from my question.

Answer (score 0):

`key` is not a property of that object, that is why it doesn't work. Key is another element with that *key* that you want to access.

In JavaScript,

```
obj.key
```

Would access the `key` *property* of `obj` object. However the following code,

```
obj["key"]
```

Would access the element at *key* "`key`". You should consider paying more attention to mapped values, also known as, Dictionary or [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: still not cleared. Can you consider my example and elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

If you literally use `info.links[i].key` it won't work since there is no value associated with the key named key. If you meant something else, please edit the question to reflect that.

It is also a bit misleading to have a data structure where the name of the link is the key. Would be better to have keys name and link, then you could get them in the same way for every link, with `info.links[i].name` and `info.links[i].link`